# Qt: Preventing memory leaks when closing windows

Tags: qt

All the example code I can find for Qt shows code that creates objects with new, but they don't get cleaned up in any window close situations. Unless Qt automatically destroys them, this seems false.

Will Qt automatically destroy all the GUI objects in the window when it's closed, or am I responsible for that myself just like I would normally be for everything else?

If I'm responsible for it, is there a "polite" way? Or can I just keep a vector of objects to destroy and run it in the reverse order they were created, calling delete on each?

For instance, here's the example for using BorderLayout:

```
Window::Window()
{
    QTextBrowser *centralWidget = new QTextBrowser;
    centralWidget->setPlainText(tr("Central widget"));

    BorderLayout *layout = new BorderLayout;
    layout->addWidget(centralWidget, BorderLayout::Center);
    layout->addWidget(createLabel("North"), BorderLayout::North);
    layout->addWidget(createLabel("West"), BorderLayout::West);
    layout->addWidget(createLabel("East 1"), BorderLayout::East);
    layout->addWidget(createLabel("East 2") , BorderLayout::East);
    layout->addWidget(createLabel("South"), BorderLayout::South);
    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Border Layout"));
}
```

This code creates a layout and 6 widgets with new QTextBrowser or new QLabel. It doesn't even try to remember them for later destruction.

Comment: If you pass a widget to a layout, the widget will be the children of the widget where the layout is established, in your case, for example, what returns createLabel will be the child of the window. On the other hand all QWidget is a QObject, and when a QObject is destroyed it will destroy your children, in your case if Window is destroyed, the layouts and internal widgets will be destroyed.

Comment: @eyllanesc "when a QObject is destroyed it will destroy **its** children", *your* children are safe ^^

Comment: The linked related questions didn't really explain best practices. I added debug code. Hitting the Close button doesn't destroy the window. It just hides it. You can window->show() again, and it pops back up. I *think* what the answers are saying is that I could, if I want, is intercept the close and schedule a "delete later" on the outermost widget, and the rest of the tree goes away. And I *think* that also means I shouldn't do anything in my window's destructors for GUI objects, only for non-GUI objects.